# Cannot get Gmail calendar to sync in Windows 8 Calendar App

Tags: windows, windows-8

My gmail syncs beautifully to the mail app. My calendar does not. I uninstalled the suite of applications (cal, mail, people) and reinstalled, but still nothing. Whenever I try to sync with my calendar I get an error.

Here's a photo of me setting up my email in Mail app. With the checkbox checked, it does not work. If I uncheck it, it works.

**EDIT:**Trying to upload photo but it keeps failing.

Annoying the heck outta me. The weird thing is, on my laptop, this all works and syncs fine. But on my surface pro, it just won't let me get my calendar on it. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have free or paid email account with Google? If you didn't already have your Calendar syncing with your Google account before the cut off date this feature won't work until there is an update to the calendar application supports **CalDav**

Comment: I have a free gmail account.

Comment: Unless your Surface Pro was setup up to sync to your account before **Jan 31 2013** what you want is not possible with the default Calendar application. Google does not support Active Exchange Sync at this time on free accounts unless they were setup before **Jan 31 2013**.

Comment: I'm confused. AES is preventing me from syncing my calendar? Even though on my laptop it works beautifully? I thought AES had to do with something about Microsoft Exchange stuff.